# how to use curl command in retrofit2

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit2

I'm trying to authenticate using https://API_KEY:API_SECRET@url'

String url = "https://key:secret@url" is not authenticating, how do i convert Curl command to retrofit2

any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: can you show your Curl Command